# Value error during grid search - epochs is not a legal parameter

Tags: valueerror, grid-search, hyperparameters, gridsearchcv

I am trying to tune my model's hyperparameters with a grid search, using a code that worked for me before without errors, as shown in the code:

```
def ann_gridsearch(dataset, dense_layers, batch_size, units, optimizer,
                   activation, method=StandardScaler):

    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test, sc = split_the_data(dataset, method=method)
    test2split = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([x_test, y_test]))
    x_test, x_val, y_test, y_val, sc = split_the_data(test2split, method=method, test_size=0.5)

    classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn=build_ann_classifier)
    parameters = {'dense_layers': dense_layers, 'batch_size': batch_size, 'units': units, 'epochs' : [150],
                  'optimizer': optimizer, 'activation': activation, 'input_dim': [input_dim]}
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=classifier,
                               param_grid=parameters,
                               return_train_score=True,
                               scoring=['accuracy', 'recall'],
                               refit='accuracy',
                               cv=3,
                               n_jobs=-1)
    grid_results = grid_search.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
    best_parameters = grid_results.best_params_
    best_accuracy = grid_results.best_score_
    grid_score = grid_results.cv_results_
    print('The best parameters are: {}'.format(best_parameters))
    print('And they give the accuracy of: {}'.format(best_accuracy))
    return grid_score
```

where my build_fn is:

```
def build_ann_classifier(dense_layers, input_dim, units, optimizer, activation, input_decrease=False):
    classifier = Sequential()
    dense_layers = dense_layers
    if input_decrease == True:
        for index, lsize in enumerate(dense_layers):
            decrease = index + 1
            # Input Layer - includes the input_shape
            if index == 0:
                classifier.add(Dense(units=units, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation=activation,
                                     input_dim=input_dim, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001)))
            else:
                units = math.floor(units * (0.8 ^ decrease))
                classifier.add(Dense(units=units, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation=activation))
    else:
        for index, lsize in enumerate(dense_layers):
            # Input Layer - includes the input_shape
            if index == 0:
                classifier.add(Dense(units=units, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation=activation,
                                     input_dim=input_dim, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001)))
            else:
                classifier.add(Dense(units=units, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation=activation))
    classifier.add(Dense(units=1, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
    classifier.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return classifier
```

running it with:

```
grid = ann_gridsearch(india_dataset, dense_layers=[(1,), (2,), (4,)], units=[50, 75, 100], batch_size=[256]
                      activation=['relu'], optimizer=['adam'])
```

The codes start to run the grid search, but after a while, it crashes with the following error:

raise ValueError('{} is not a legal parameter'.format(params_name))

ValueError: epochs is not a legal parameter

I couldn't find any relevant answers anywhere. Any ideas why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

try "epoch"->"nb_epoch", tarting Keras 2.0, nb_epoch argument has been renamed to epochs, but KerasClassifier doesn't seem to change.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).